# How to bake multiple instances with randomized emission/material?

Tags: materials, uv, texture-baking, procedural, instances

I am trying to bake instances into one UV map/texture for exporting to other software. They all have the same material, which gives them different emission color based on their object data.

Node setup:
[image: Material Setup for Instances]

For reference, here is a picture of my scene (the instances are the Christmas lights):
[image: My Scene]

## Problem

I can't for the life of me get the cord, and all the instances into one UV map.

## Question

Is it even possible to bake such a material? Is it possible to embed this information into some exporting format (I.e. FBX, or OBJ)? How would one go about exporting these Christmas lights?

## Appendix

[image: UV map]

This is my UV map, with the lights outlined in red. I can only seem to select one light at a time in the editor (as they are instances). So I can only UV unwrap one light.